# How should i insert an Html content in a bookmark openxml power point

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

How should i insert an Html content in a bookmark for a power point using open XML

Is there any reference or samples i could refer?

I am using placeholders for replacing text currently. But i need to render an html content with some inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint doesn't render HTML content.

You could try adding a web browser control and using that to render the HTML. That's not a perfect solution; there are security issues that MS sometimes "solves" by disabling the control and ActiveX controls don't work on Mac at all.